# Why does my Ethernet port sometimes not work?

Tags: 10.04, hardware, networking, thinkpad, lenovo

I've noticed that my Ethernet port works fine once, but after it's disconnected and i connect to a wireless network and I go and try to plug the Ethernet port back in, it doesn't work until I reboot. Why is this?!

Also, the lights light up but it's like the Ubuntu doesn't see it. Is there a way to reboot the Ethernet port programmaticly through Terminal? I've also tried to delete and readd Auto Ethernet through the Network Preferences.

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad L512 with Ubuntu 10.04

==UPDATE==

I did the first step Maco said to do and here is what I got:

```
oscargodson@ubuntu:~$ sudo service network-manager stop
[sudo] password for oscargodson: 
network-manager stop/waiting
oscargodson@ubuntu:~$ sudo ifconfig eth0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot allocate memory
oscargodson@ubuntu:~$ sudo dhclient eth0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client V3.1.3
Copyright 2004-2009 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot allocate memory
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot allocate memory
Listening on LPF/eth0/60:eb:69:02:50:f0
Sending on   LPF/eth0/60:eb:69:02:50:f0
Sending on   Socket/fallback
receive_packet failed on eth0: Network is down
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
send_packet: Network is down
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
send_packet: Network is down
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
send_packet: Network is down
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
send_packet: Network is down
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
send_packet: Network is down
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
send_packet: Network is down
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
send_packet: Network is down
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

I've tried everything Maco suggested and finally figured out my memory isn't low although I keep getting a SIOCIFFLAGS: Cannot allocate memory error. I have over 1GB of RAM free as we speak.

I found this page:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/weird-ethernet-problem-838220/

And did what the person there said which was:

```
lspci| grep -i ethernet
dmesg | grep -i ethernet
```

And it gave me some output and the last command gave me:

```
r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
```

I then tried Maco's stuff again and i didn't get the error anymore, however, the Ethernet still doesn't connect although now it doesn't give me the memory allocation error.

Comment: the `dmesg | grep -i ethernet` was just another way of doing what I looked in 70-persistent-net.rules -- both lspci & dmesg commands were rather exploratory

Comment: Any other ideas? :(

Comment: Looks like i got it up and working again if i do those commands above then sudo service network-manager stop, then sudo ifconfig, then sudo dhclient, THEN sudo service network-manager start. How can i make it do this on start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like bug.  Lets dig in.

First, stop Network Manager: `sudo service network-manager stop`

Then, plug in the cable and bring up the interface `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` and tell it to ask for a new dhcp lease `sudo dhclient eth0`  (I'm guessing it's eth0, if not use the right name)

Did it work? If so, file a bug on Network Manager:  `ubuntu-bug -p network-manager`

If not, try reloading the network driver.  This should simulate a reboot to the ethernet port.  To find out your driver, look in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules  You'll see some bits like:

```
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:f1:4c:01:94:3e", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Finding the one that matches your interface's name, look at what's in the parentheses where mine says r8169.  That's your module's name.

```
sudo modprobe -r r8169 && sudo modprobe r8169
```

(replacing r8169 with your module's name) Try the dhclient step again.  If that worked, I suspect it's a kernel bug.  `ubuntu-bug -p linux`

Comment: I did the first thing you had me do, and I got the above (i edited my original post). The 2nd one i dont have a /udev/ directory in /usr/? Whys this?

Comment: Because I screwed up, sorry! I meant /etc/udev...

Comment: Maco, im getting the same result. After doing this (mine is also r8169) i ran sudo ifconfig eth0 up and it said the same as before "cannot allocate memory" then i did sudo dhclient eth0 and it gave me the output that i pasted above. Not sure if this helps but since this only happens when I go home, i suspect this only happens when i: use ethernet, unplug, use wifi, disconnect wifi, then plug in ethernet. Thanks so much! I really want this to work. It's a PITA to reboot every morning :)

Comment: what's the output of `free -m` ?  Are you actually out of memory?

Comment: Hmm, seems we might have found something: free -m output: http://pastebin.com/syX9jUx0 (think it's because it's 666? :P, but the first time I ran this I got only 32 free!) Here are all my running processes also: http://pastebin.com/DRVeMyht -- Any ideas?

Comment: See my updated post above. I got that error to go away

Comment: I'm marking it as correct as it's as correct as it's going get. Thanks so much, and im reporting the bug now on LP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same problem. Wireless works on boot provided router is switched on beforehand. If its not then I have to go through the process of setting up a network again. Wired connection refuses to work at all with the
ifconfig: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot allocate memory
coming up.
N.B. This is using BrowserLinux (based on Puppy Linux)